Rmarkdown - Formatting not applied
I am trying to generate a pdf from Rmarkdown, which works fine. However, the formatting is not recognized (code below).
All package that miktex asked for are installed. I've tried xelatex and pdflatex.
Does anybody knows what is missing? I've just install Rstudio on this PC, had it on another one before.
Centered text
\begin{centre}
try something different
\end




Does anybody knows what is missing??

Yes, you forgot to type {center} at the end (not "centre" as you mistyped in the question).
Since you do not type any coherent LaTeX, it was  assumed that the included backslashes and curly braces are part of the raw plain text, so in the latest Rstudio version even the source will be changed automatically to ...
Centered text \\begin{centre} try something different \\end

... after saving  or rendering, to make it clear that what the program sees is not LaTeX, but simple text with symbols, which are used for who knows why.
Whereas ...
Centered text \begin{center} try something different \end{center}

... will be rendered almost always correctly.
However, under some circumstances even a correct LaTeX environment (\begin{whatever} ...\end{whatever}) or LaTeX command (\whatever{whatever}) could be not recognized properly as LaTeX code during the conversion, so it is always  safer mark the LaTeX chunk as a LaTeX cell in this way:
Not centered text  
```{=latex}
\begin{centre} try something different \end{center}
```

Note that while \end without argument will be translated to \\end in markdown text and you obtain a PDF with "\end",inside the  LaTeX cell, \end will pbe passed "as is" to LaTeX, so producing a fatal error (no PDF, amd moreover a long and unprofitable attempt to solve the issue updating the latex packages).
Finally, the most correct syntax is:
Not centered text

::: {.center data-latex=""}
try something different
:::

Why this is better? Because now you can use the markdown syntax also
inside the centered text  (e.g. *foo* instead of \emph{foo})

Thank you for the explanation Fran! It did make it work and I will keep that in mind!
